# php - how to redirect to be 100% sure that REFERRAL cleaned after redirect

Tags: php, redirect

How do I redirect users and be sure that the HTTP_REFERER does not transfer to the next page after reaching a page called redirect.php.

The program flow is as follows:

1) On page at http://example.com/index.php (contains a link to redirect.php)

2) User click on the link to redirect.php and it sends the header('Location: http://otherlocation.com/index.php');

3) I need to prevent otherlocation.com from seeing the HTTP_REFERER from `http://example.com/index.php`

I have tried:

```
 header('Location:redirect.php');
```

This does not work as HTTP_REFERER is populated with the value from the first page (http://example.com/index.php).

Comment: the question formulation is not clear. What do you want to do ? Also, what have you tried ??

Comment: sorry for my english, its hard to describ. i add some detailed description of step-by-step what i am do and need.

Comment: @abrahab, updated my answer check out the new code.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar give me some time please. are you 100% sure that 302 redirect will give the HTTP_REFERER of `redirect.php`, but not of `http://domain.com/index.php` ?

Comment: @abrahab here check this link. http://www.dankind.com/blog/hiding-the-http-referer-with-php-js-or-meta/ , i tried and it worked fine for me.

Comment: [This](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#83448) might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill up HTTP_REFERER depending by browser, not server-side

You may try redirect user by

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://otherlocation.com/index.php" />
<script>document.location = 'http://otherlocation.com/index.php';</script>
```

browser not fill up HTTP_REFERER at this moment (IMHO)

At firefox this not work :(

Comment: yes, the way, but will lose thaffic without javascript enabled :(

Comment: you can post with  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://otherlocation.com/index.php">

Answer (score 0):

to redirect using PHP send a header request to the browser. try this.

```
header('Location:redirect.php',true,302);
exit;
```

The above code will set the `HTTP_REFERRER` trace to current page. hence deleting the trace from previous page.

Comment: seems that this kind of redirect send the http_referral of the page that linked to redirect.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
header("Location:redirect.php");
```

or if you want some delay or countdown, you can use.

```
// 5 is the seconds of the delay to go to the page you've entered.

header("refresh: 5; redirect.php";
```